# Filter a list without knowing the list type

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm writing a Kotlin function to search a List, but the list type will be based on user input from a Spinner (`_selectedRuleset` is set by another function).

```
private val _selectedRuleset = MutableLiveData<List<*>>()
val selectedRuleset: LiveData<List<*>> get() = _selectedRuleset    

fun search (term: String) {
     val pattern = term.toRegex()
     val rules : List<*>? = when (searchTerm.value) {
         @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
         "category1" -> selectedRuleset.value as List<Type1>
         "category2" -> selectedRuleset.value as List<Type2>
         "category3" -> selectedRuleset.value as List<Type3>
         else -> selectedRuleset.value as List<Type1>
     }
  rules.filter {}
}
```

is there a way to cast the appropriate list type to `rules` (without using `Suppress`) so that when I try to filter `rules` the compiler knows which type of list it is?

Comment: No, the compiler cannot possibly determine the type. This is a warning, not an error. If you know the type is safe to cast to, then suppressing the warning is appropriate. Your code above doesn't look safe, but I assume that's because it's incomplete.

Comment: In the code as written, the cast isn't doing anything. The compiler will still consider rules to be a `List<*>?`

Comment: @JacobBotuck Haha, good point.

Answer (score 0):

You can make Type1, Type2 and Type3 all implement some common interface like FilterableByRegex and solve this without any casting.